# ReactJS/Enzyme: How to test a container if it gets data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, mocha.js, enzyme

How can I test a react container with enzyme and mocha? I'm using a container to give the component some data. So this is how my container and the component look like:

**/imports/ui/components/example.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Header, Divider, Container, Segment, Loader } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        const   { data, isLoading } = this.props,

        if (isLoading)
            return (<Loader active inverted size='massive' className='animated fadeIn' />)

        return (
            <Container text className='m-t-1 m-b-1 animated bounceInDown'>
                <Segment raised padded>
                    <Header as='h1' floated='right'>{ data.title }</Header>
                    <Divider clearing />
                </Segment>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

**/imports/ui/containers/example.jsx**

```
import Example from '/imports/ui/components/example.jsx'

export default createContainer((props) => {
    const   id           = props.params.id,
            subscription = Meteor.subscribe('something', id),
            isLoading    = !subscription.ready(),
            data         = Collection.find().fetch()

    return {
        data: data,
        isLoading
    }
}, Example)
```

Now I first want to test for displaying the `<Loader />` component if the data is not loaded at all - which is working so far.

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { expect } from 'chai'

// Import Container
import Example from '/imports/ui/containers/example.js'

describe('Example', () => {
    describe('component', () => {
        describe('<Example />', () => {
            it('should show the <Loader /> component by default', () => {
                const   wrapper     = mount(<Example params={ { id: 'ueRunYgz4gwHquiYK' } } />),
                        container   = wrapper.first('div'),
                        loader      = wrapper.find('Loader')

                expect(container).to.have.length(1)
                expect(loader).to.have.length(1)
            })

            it('should show the <Container /> component when data has loaded', () => {
                const   wrapper   = mount(<Example params={ { id: diseaseID } } />),
                        container = wrapper.find('Example')

                expect(container).to.have.length(1)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

But the second test fails as I don't know how to get the `isLoading` to a `false` value

Answer (score 0):

`Example` is recieving `isLoading` as a prop. Can you mount `Example` with the prop `isLoading={false}`?

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <Example
    params={{id: diseaseID}}
    isLoading={false} 
  />
), container = wrapper.find('Example')
```

Comment: No, as this prop will be used by the container, not by the component, which will be the 'next level'...

Comment: Are you saying that `Example` does not recieve and does not use the `isLoading` prop?

Comment: Maybe it is a bad code writing or bad naming... There is an `Example` component and also an `Example` container, which gives the data to the component. I'm importing the container (!) to the test. So setting the prop, will send it to the container. But there it will get the 'real' value, so isLoading is still `true`

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry I missed that.  I see what you're saying now.  Can you mock or use sinon to create a spy on the `Meteor.subscribe` param to get the `subscription` property into the state you want?

Comment: I think that will be the right way, but I'm new to this testing stuff and I did not use sinon so far. Could you please post a simple example for that? Would be really great!